# Запомнить адрес страницы при наведении на ссылку javascript

Tags: javascript

Все мы прекрасно знаем, что при наведении на любую ссылку, в браузере возникает окошко, которое отображает адрес ссылки. Обычно оно (окошко) появляется в левом нижнем углу окна браузера. Скажите, есть ли возможность, получить значение этого этой ссылки из браузера при наведен на нее курсора мыши средствами javascript или установив ее в определенный контейнер?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Proof of concept, так сказать:

```
<a href='https://google.com'>google</a><br>
<a href='http://ya.ru'>yandex</a><br>
link: <span id='href'></span>
<script>
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i in els) {
    els[i].onmouseover = function() {
        var e = document.getElementById('href');
        e.innerText = this.href;
    }
}
</script>
```

Оно же на jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jokghghp/

Comment: `innerText` [не поддерживается filrefox-ом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Comment: Немного подправил [ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/0es3kL7j/)

Comment: @romeo Ну так это же чисто демонстрация принципиальной возможности, без учета особенностей браузеров, можно было хоть alert'ом выводить. :)

Comment: @romeo - чуть позже посмотрю, как получится на практике - пока все круто.

Comment: @Yaant - спасибо за интересный код.